# Find shape of nested array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array like this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((30,2))
```

this gives me an array with 30 rows and 2 columns and `a.shape returns >> (30,2)`

However, if I check the shape of `a[0].shape >> (2,)` but i expect to see `(1,2)`
is there a way to create this array(30,2) and still get the shape of the individual elements as (1,2)?

Comment: You'll need to reshape each 1D slice in order to add a new dimension to it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use [integer *array* indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing), the first axis does not disappear:

```
In [8]: a[[0]].shape
Out[8]: (1, 2)
```

The first axis will have the same length as the list used to index the first axis. Since `len([0])` is 1, the length of the first axis of `a[[0]]` is 1.

In contrast, `a[0]` is a basic slice, which according to [the rules](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) removes the associated axis.

The two types of indexing have a certain consistency: If we think of the the scalar `0` as a length-0 array-like, and the list `[0]` as a length-1 array-like, then `a[index]` is returning an array whose first axis has the same length as `index`. This property remains true even when `index` itself is an `N`-dimensional array.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to [unutbu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54788689) you may also use

```
a[0, np.newaxis].shape
>>> (1, 2)
```

An [explanation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) can be found almost at the same spot as the other reference.